# SP2010 REST API from Javascript: how to set multiple fields to filter on in the URL

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, url, rest

weird but i can't figure this out or find a solution anywhere....

I want to filter on two values on a GET in REST URL from javascript. So since this is from ECMA I am just using filtering in the url...

something like:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Table?$filter=Color eq 'Red'&Active eq false
```

doesn't work so I have tried:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Table?$filter=((Color eq 'Red') and (Active eq false)
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Table?$filter=Color eq 'Red' and Active eq false
etc
```

i know that you can only use one operator at a time in a URL but I not sure how to set two or three field filters in one URL like this

appreciate any help.

Comment: Just an FYI as I know this does not pertain directly to your question, you can not filter on multi-selectable choice fields. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/how-can-i-filter-based-on-choice-fields-when-using-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everywhere in this answer replace `sp2010` with your site url, `Table` with your list name, `PortalHomeDataContext` with your site name (without spaces) + `DataContext` and `RestTest.ServiceReference1` with your generated namespace.

This is tested against a SharePoint 2010 site:

```
http://sp2010/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Table?$filter=(Color eq 'Red') and (Active eq false)
```

A very efficient way of getting the syntax (provided you know C# and LINQ) is the following:

1. Create a Console Application using visual studio
2. Add a service reference to `http://sp2010/_vti_bin/listdata.svc`
3. Change to console application to something like this:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   using RestTest.ServiceReference1;

   namespace RestTest
   {
     class Program
     {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
         var context = new PortalHomeDataContext(new Uri("http://sp2010/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
         context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
         var data = from d in context.Table
                    where d.Color == "Red" && d.Active == false
                    select d;
         foreach (var row in data)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(row.Title);
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Now start Fiddler (download from http://fiddler2.com/) and run the console app. Fiddler will show the url generated by the console app.

Comment: Just to tack on a tool I find useful with Chrome is *Dev HTTP Client*. It hav a very simple interface for composing HTTP requests. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en

Comment: Very cool! C# yes, Linq I am a little less familiar with however it's one of those on the list to learn type things so...thanks!

Comment: Also just the general tested URL you provided worked for me which I appreciate, but even more so the examples for finding URL from console!

Answer (score 4):

I tried this using the 2013 api in SharePoint online, but I think the filter syntax should work the same...

You need to specify your boolean field as 1 or zero, like this...

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('defects')/items?$select=Color,Title,ID&$filter=Color eq 'Red' and Active eq 1&$top=100
```

Also, make sure you are using internal names, not display names.

Comment: I used the ODATA Query Builder from the SharePoint Online App Store to construct this.  An awesome tool, although it does not seem to support boolean fields (And no, I am not affiliated with it).

Comment: Thanks...I assume that tool is only available in SP2013 since you mentioned app store? The link you provided worked but so did false from previous answer...I suppose at least in sp2010you can use either?