# REST Query based on Expanded columns in Choice field (Listdata.svc)

Tags: 2010, javascript, rest, listdata.svc

I have a SP2010 client side app making REST calls.  I have a large list that I would like to make a filtered query using the value of a none or many choice field called 'displays'. I have no access to add to server side code on this one.

When I 'expand' the query I can access the value of the choice like so

```
myDataVar.d.results[0].Displays.results[0].Value
```

Because dragging 1000 rows to the client to show 20 is cruel and unusual network punishment I need to filter `d.results` on `.Displays.results[0].Value`.

I have tried this:

```
[site]/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/MasterDataList?$filter=Displays/Value eq 'Wide'
```

I am rewarded with the error message

> "No property 'Value' exists in type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' at position 9."

Per [another thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/how-can-i-filter-based-on-choice-fields-when-using-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-20) I have tried

```
/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/MasterDataList?$filter=DisplaysValue eq 'Wide'&$expand=Displays
```

error:

*No property 'DisplaysValue' exists in type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity' at position 0.*

Testing for 'Displays' without the 'Value' suffix the error is:

*Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' and 'System.String' at position 9.*

---

My stuck back in 2010 again thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that the field is a multiple choice field and the example are for a single choice field.  I haven't come across a solution for the multi-choice field in REST.  You may want to consider redesigning to multiple single-choice fields.

Comment: This does seem to be the line that cannot be crossed so far.  No multi-select  choice filtering in the 2010 listdata.svc REST. :(   Sadly, while ideal, I cannot make changes to the structure.